# How can I select an element that has exactly the same name as another element with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

My university's system for checking my kardex is old and poorly constructed. That is why it has fragmented the html, elements with the same name, etc.

I want to click the `SELECCIONAR` button, but there are two.

I want to do is choose an element because two elements with the same name but that do two different things.

How can I select for example button 2 that has the plain text `AC`?

Comment: you can set the CSS property to hide the element.

Comment: Just so to understand, why would you look to remove an element?

Comment: Because there are two elements with the same name but that do two different things

Comment: We can differentiate the two elements, can you provide the HTML for them ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I will ask a new question with more details and providing the HTML code

Comment: You can edit this question itself

Comment: It is already edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can differentiate based on text like `EG` and `AC`

`xpath` for **AC- SELECCIONAR** `button` would be :-

```
//td[text()='AC']/following-sibling::td/input
```

you can write the same for `EG`.

You can click on it like below (in case you want to)

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[text()='AC']/following-sibling::td/input"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Enter this: `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='AC']/following-sibling::td/input"))` And I get this: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame: element is not a frame`

Comment: you were quick, try the code above, I have updated.